# How to display posts by author in a separate page, other than author.php?

Tags: categories, pages, author

I have an author.php page that displays two kind of posts:

1. first section displays latest 10 posts(games) from all categories, except one.
2. second section displays latest 10 posts only from that category that are excepted at the first section.

With two kinds of posts, I put one red button link under each section, to see all posts by the same author.  Each button link should link to the right page: the first button link that should link to a page with the posts belonging  to the first section, and  the last button link that should link to a another page with the posts belonging to the second section.

On that pages I think it's easy to display post by categories, my problem is that I really don't know how to create these pages and how to link to them.

Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have described four different elements - lists of posts by category, link to category archive, list by author, link to author archive. I am little fuzzy which of this (and/or archives) precisely you need help with?

Comment: If you read the title I think that is enough: How to display posts by author in a separate page, other than author.php? Thanks anyway.

Comment: Please don't scoff at requests for clarification. Not everyone is native English speaker and not everyone (on both sides of it) has perfect command of WordPress terminology. It's in your best interested that question is refined to be easy to provide precise and fitting answer for.

Comment: @Rarst, I'm not scoff at anyone, I will never do that. I respect every answer and comment in part, be they even useless, as long as someone has taken from his spare time to answer me. I just thought the title says everything you need to better clarify what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving set of posts by some criteria is typically realm of *secondary loop*.

You can use [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) template tag or `WP_Query` object which both support [author parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters) in arguments:

- `author` (numerical ID)
- `author_name`.

Comment: That makes sense to me. I'll try put all together and I hope the pagination will work also. Any suggestion about how to link that pages from author.php? Thanks.

Comment: @LiviuCostache how do you imagine to implement pagination with multiple loops on page? In general pagination only works easily with main loop (the one WP performs internally before template load), otherwise it is challenging to implement.

Comment: Initially I thought you were having a bad day and I overlooked but now I tend to think so is you. You actually do not answer to questions, it seems like you rebuked those who ask you inappropriate questions, instead of calmly explain. From where comes this nerve up to treat people like this? Because the role of moderator you talk in this manner?

Comment: @LiviuCostache please understand that while you might consider your question clear it might not be to other people. That's why I asked for clarification initially (which you declined to try) and about pagination later (which your question makes no mention of). If you have issue with my behavior as mod please post on http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/ or contact administrators directly http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/contact , I would be happy to have situation reviewed.

Comment: Well, that escalated quickly...